# How to understand a website is using gzip compression?

Tags: java, html, .htaccess, selenium, gzip

I am trying to check any website is using gzip or not?

I found this explanation on Nibbler,

> We check if pages use GZIP compression for smaller page sizes and
>   faster downloading

Is there anything in html that shows gzip is used? How can I understand that?

Comment: Compression is on a lower layer. HTML doesn't know whether it will be compressed when it's served or not.

Comment: what about the `content-encoding` response header?

Comment: @Kayaman how can I reach that point? I am trying to reach it in Selenium

Comment: What point? Compression is between the client and the server. The actual content doesn't know or care whether it's compressed or not, and it's handled transparently in their respective libraries.

Comment: @GameDroids let me check it,

Comment: HTML is the language a web page is written. GZIP takes place in the HTTP transport. You should check the HTTP response headers for content-encoding: gzip

Comment: But the client first has to tell the server which encoding it supports by using the `Accept-Encoding` header field: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression

Comment: You can check if it is enabled or not throw many online tools 
https://sitechecker.pro/fr/gzip-test/
https://smallseotools.com/check-gzip-compression/

Comment: @Hammed I am trying to do what they did in Java with Selenium.

Comment: @Ahmet Aziz Beşli I understand , I think that they check response headers and find content-encoding: gzip , I find it in my chrome developer tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
URL uri = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) uri.openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding","gzip");
Map<String, List<String>> map = connection.getHeaderFields();
for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("Key : " + entry.getKey() +
        " ,Value : " + entry.getValue());
}
```

Content-Encoding with value `[]` will be printed.

Answer (score 3):

Open chrome Developer Tools

Go to the "Network" tab and reload the page.

Choose the appropriate page/file on the left

then the "Headers" tab on the right pane.

Under "Response Headers" you should see "Content-Encoding: gzip"

[image]