# what is this request response format?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, web-scraping, request

i'm trying to scrape a website but the thing is that i get this as a response (most likely javascript ? ). I am using request in order to send requests to the website.
Is it possible to convert it to a parsable format ? I thought of using jQuery to send request an accept a certain response format.But as of right now i'm mainly trying to identify the type of response i'm getting. Thank you.

The response i get :

[image]

Comment: gzip? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely gzip

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures

Click F12 and look at the response in a browser.

HTML is often gzipped and if you are not using a client that unzips it, then you will get the raw zip

[How to understand a website is using gzip compression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58283567/how-to-understand-a-website-is-using-gzip-compression)